# Disable auto suggest typing when using the CTRL key

Tags: keyboard, macos, text, auto-complete, autocorrect

Sometimes when I press and release the CTRL key while my cursor is in a text field, the letter "I" gets inserted and an autosuggest list gets opened.

[image]

I really really dislike this because I often press and release the CTRL key without wanting to type anything.

How can I disable this functionality?

Comment: Do you have CTRL mapped to also do Escape when pressed and released?

Comment: No. The only keyboard item I have changed is mapping Caps Lock to Escape using Karabiner.

Comment: @CoryKlien: Do you have Caps Lock mapped to Control with Seil or System Preferences? It's possible that you actually have CTRL mapped to both CTRL and Escape, then Caps mapped to CTRL..

Comment: Turns out I actually did have CTRL mapped to Escape in Karabiner, somehow I missed it before! It was only mapped to Escape if I pressed and released CTRL without hitting any other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261065/210615):

It's the auto completion from the built in spell checker and after a lengthy search I found the solution in [Apples Discussion Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30061769#message30061769):

```
defaults write -g NSUseSpellCheckerForCompletions -bool false
```

Afterwards restart affected programs and Esc just cancels searches again.